# Remove Focus on textForm field Flutter Web once click out of the form

Tags: flutter

Hy guys.
TextFormField flutter web once you click into the form, cursor start blinking awaiting input.
What I want to do is if I click outside this form the cursor will gone and focus on the form closed.

this is my code as:

```
TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,fontSize: 13,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(

                  contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                  ),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,fontSize: 13),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Color(0xffe7e7e7),
                  hintText: 'Cerca da Nome - ID - EAN'),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Scaffold with a GestureDetector() and set unfocus() to the current FocusScopeNode

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
      if(!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
        currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
      }
    },
    child: Scaffold()
  );
}
```